# Mattermost: Customizable action on direct message

Tags: mattermost

Is there a way currently (v 5.10.0) to trigger auto-replies and/or customizable actions on receiving a DM for a certain user?

Comment: if the posted answer satisfies the question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality out of the box but you can create Mattermost plugins for any such task.

Here's an example plugin that doesn't allow you to send direct messages - https://github.com/Brightscout/mattermost-plugin-disable-dm

Mattermost plugins documentation is available over here - https://developers.mattermost.com/extend/plugins/webapp/hello-world/ which contains documentation on everything a Mattermost plugin can do.